# Theme settings doesn't work

Tags: theming, debugging

When i `dpm` that `$vars`, in `classes` key, there is no `r_style` class, whyyyy? I tried clear cache through `devel` module, but still the same, what i am doing wrong?

```
name = JH Template
core = 7.x
engine = phptemplate

styles[all][] = css/style.css
settings[bg_style] = 'r_style'
```

**theme-settings.php**

```
function jh_process_html(&$vars) {
    $vars['classes'] .= ' ' . theme_get_setting('bg_style');
    dpm($vars); // in classes string isn't r_style class
}
```

**EDIT:** the real question is, why `theme_get_setting('bg_style')` returns `NULL`

**SOLVED:** that jh_process_html function must be in template.php file, but i don't understand that drupal :D, because that function was executed even in if it was in theme-settings.php, but actually just sometimes and it causes some fails like that theme_get_setting returned null. I don't know why this happened, but it's really funny after so many years of development of drupal, this magic happened.

Comment: Why do you expect that to work? Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: @AlexGill: pleas check again the code, i added one line, where i use dpm

Comment: Use template_preprocess_html(), see answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
function jh_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
$vars['classes_array'][] = theme_get_setting('bg_style');
}
```

You need to do this at an earlier stage of the processing.

Comment: After dpm, i see in classes_array is one NULL item, that is because theme_get_setting('bg_style') gives me NULL. This is where the problem is.

Comment: Some sort of caching going on there probably...